# correct tab is not open when page is loaded

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter to make a web application, When the user registers with invalid credentials I am trying to reload my registration tab which is located on my authentication view, when the authentication view reloads my log in tab is displayed first because by default this is set to the active tab.

authentication view

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="authentication_tab">
  <li class="tabs-title is-active"><a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true">Login</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-title"><a href="#panel2">Sign Up</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-content" data-tabs-content="authentication_tab">
  <div class="tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1">
  <?php $this->load->view('authentication/login');?>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-panel" id="panel2">
  <?php $this->load->view('authentication/reg');?>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php $this->load->view('templates/footer');?>
```

loading my authentication view after validation has taken place

```
public function reg()
    {
$data['title'] = 'Home Page';
$this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
$this->load->view('authentication/authentication#panel2');
    }
```

Comment: Do you have JS that checks for hash-tag in URL? If not, than you must do some checks for it (PHP or JS side)

Comment: no i dont have anything in my url that checks for hash-tag

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know PHP at all...

but can you not put the PHP logic within the div tag to load the "is-active"?

Also, is the class not just "active"?  I use Bootstrap and the class is simply "active" and not "is-active".

Comment: im using foundation and i copied the tabs straight from the docs

Answer (score 0):

In whatever controller you are using just decide (depending on the actions taken) which tab you want opened. Let us say the tab you want is 'thisOne', then pass a variable to your view, something like $open_tab='thisOne'.

In your view, before each tab, simply check the variable to see if it equals the current tab, and then set a class.
Use this:

```
<?php echo ('name_of_tab' == $open_tab) ? 'is_active' : ''; ?>

In your tab LI
<li class="tabs-title <?php echo ('name_of_tab' == $open_tab) ? 'is_active' : ''; ?>">Blah Blah</li>
```

In your controller you can set the default tab first, then overide that depending on users posts or actions etc.

Hope that helps,

Paul.